# method evaluating a word with vowels in alphabetical order

Tags: ruby

This piece of code returns true or false if a words vowels are in alphabetical order.

```
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
  y = word.split('')
  x = y.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  (0...(x.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    x[i] <= x[i + 1]
  end

end
```

However I don't quite understand how it does that. in particular I don't understand the very last line `x[i] <= x[i + 1]`. I'm also not very familiar with the `.all` method. why not just use `.each` instead?

Aren't the values of `x[i]` or `x[i+1]` letters? How can we compare letters values with less than or equal to? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.all?` will return true is the given block evaluates to `true` for all the elements in the enumeration.
Here you are checking if all the elements are lesser than or equal to its next element.

The less than or equal uses the Integer ordinal of the character for comparison.

eg:

```
> 'a'.ord
# => 97 
> 'b'.ord
# => 98
```

So `'b'` is greater than `'a'`

Comment: thanks I had no idea about integer ordinals which is why I was so confused

Answer (score 1):

Here first you are splitting the argument **"Word"** in a character array and stored it in **"X"**.
Then You have selected all the vowels and stored it in **"X"** using the **"include?"** method. And then by using **.all?** method you are checking for all the elements between the index **0 to x.length-1** excluding the x.length-1 index. And yes You can also use **.each** here instead of **.all**.
And there is a method **spaceship (<=>) method** that can be used to compare two strings in relation to their alphabetical ranking. The <=> method returns 0 if the strings are identical, -1 if the left hand string is less than the right hand string, and 1 if it is greater.
Hope This will help You!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the naming is the most confusing part of this method. Let's break it down:

```
y = word.split('')
```

should really be `my_letters = word.split('')`, since it returns an array with each letter as a string (like `["s", "o", "m", "e"]`)

```
x = y.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }
```

should be `my_vowels  = my_letters.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }`. This will return an array of vowels from your word (like `["o", "e"]`)

```
(0...(my_vowels.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    my_vowels[i] <= my_vowels[i + 1]
end
```

`all?` will only return true if the given block is true for all elements (See [Enumerable#all?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all?))

We have two elements in our array ["o", "e"], the `all?` is performed once, shown by the `(0..1).all?`. It passes the 0 index to the block and evaluates each string with the one after it.

`my_vowels[0] <= my_vowels[1]` represents `"o" <= "e"` in our example, which evaluates to false.

`<=` [(see Comparable docs)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Comparable.html#method-i-3C-3D) will be true so long as the first string has a lesser or equal value than the other. For strings, value is determined by an Integer ordinal which you can find by calling `.ord` on the string.

Answer (score 0):

And just as a reference, this is how I would write this function in a more Rubyish way:

```
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
    vowels = ->char{'aeiou'[char.downcase]}
    vowels_in_word = word.chars.select &vowels
    vowels_in_word == vowels_in_word.sort
end
```